# Crontab not running script automatically

Tags: python, django, cron

I created a custom python command called `expire_lesson.py`. In my terminal when I run python3 manage.py expire_lesson, the command successfully executes. I have added a cron job `* * * * * cd /Users/james/Desktop/elearning && python3 manage.py expire_lesson` to run the script every minute. The issue is the cron job is not working. I believe it has something to do with the location of my cron job, but am unsure how to find the exact location, or if there is another issue. I would greatly appreciate any help in adding a cron job that runs `expire_lesson` successfully.

```
class Command(BaseCommand):

    help = 'Expires old lesson objects'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        Lesson.objects.filter(lesson_end__lt=timezone.now()).delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

try with full path off python3 and then update your crontab line with full python3 path something like...

`* * * * * cd /Users/james/Desktop/elearning && /usr/bin/python3 manage.py expire_lesson`

Comment: It still seems to not be running

Comment: what is your full python3 path?

Comment: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3